# Evaluating integral $\iint_{D} 2x-y \,dA$ bounded by circle of a given radius

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate the definite integral $$\iint_{D} 2x-y \,dA$$ where  $D$ is bounded by the circle with center at the origin and a radius $2$.

This particular problem looks like a simple case of converting a definite integral to polar coordinates then solving.

I know that in polar coordinates:

- $x$ becomes $rcos(\theta)$
- $y$ becomes $rsin(\theta)$
- $dA$ becomes $r\, dr\, d\theta$

The integral is bounded by the radius, $0 \le r \le 2$, and $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$. So I have the integral:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^2 2(rcos(\theta))-(rsin(\theta)) \, r \, dr \,d\theta$$

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^2 r^2(2cos(\theta)-sin(\theta)) \, dr \,d\theta$$

$$\frac{2^3}{3} \int_0^{2\pi} 2cos(\theta)-sin(\theta) \,d\theta$$

But the remaining integral $\int_0^{2\pi} 2cos(\theta)-sin(\theta) \,d\theta$ evaluates to $0$. Intuitively, a circle with some radius cannot have an area that is $0$, so this result is obviously incorrect.

The visual representation of the inner integral is as follows:

[image: Visual representation of inner integral]

Is this answer correct? Where did I go wrong?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Note that your integral isn't the area of a circle. The area of a circle would be the same region, but instead of f(x, y) =2x-y you'd have f(x, y) =1. So, instead of the area of a circle, we're evaluating a function over a circle. Additionally, this function has symmetry about the origin, so integrating it over a region symmetric about the origin should make it be 0

Comment: You have no mistake in your calculations. Just have in mind that in general a double integral will represent an area only when where is nothing inside the integral, that is, $\iint_D dA=Area(D)$. Once some function appears inside the integral the intuition of the area will not work well, and $\iint_D f(x,y)dA$ will be the volume between $f(x,y)$ and the plane $x,y$ (as when $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ represents the area between the function $f(x)$ and the $x$-axis.)

Comment: To build on the previous two comments: Note that $\iint_D 2x - y dA = 2\iint_D x dA - \iint_D y dA$. But because the circle is about the origin, $x$ is negative on one half and positive on the other, and symmetrically so. Therefore $\iint_D x dA = 0$ as the negative and positive sides cancel out. And the $\iint_D y dA = 0$ for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

You're not wrong. The answer is 0. This is because the process of doing a double integral means finding the volume. When the answer is 0, this means no depth exists for the integral, so you are left with the xy plane.

Answer (score 1):

The function $z=2x-y$ with domain $x^2+y^2 \leq 4$ is odd about the line $x=y$ , also if you split the domain about $x=y$ it is symmetric. Hence the integral vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through the integral step by step.

You have correctly set up the integral in polar coordinates:

∫ from 0 to 2π ∫ from 0 to 2 (2rcos(θ) - rsin(θ)) r dr dθ

Now, let's evaluate the inner integral first:

∫ from 0 to 2 (2rcos(θ) - rsin(θ)) r dr

= ∫ from 0 to 2 (2r^2cos(θ) - rsin(θ)) dr

= [r^3cos(θ) + r^2sin(θ)] evaluated from 0 to 2

= (2^3cos(θ) + 2^2sin(θ)) - (0 + 0)

= (8cos(θ) + 4sin(θ))

Now, plug this result back into the outer integral:

∫ from 0 to 2π (8cos(θ) + 4sin(θ)) dθ

= [8sin(θ) - 4cos(θ)] evaluated from 0 to 2π

= (8sin(2π) - 4cos(2π)) - (8sin(0) - 4cos(0))

= (0 - 4) - (0 - 4)

= -4 + 4

= 0

So, the integral evaluates to 0. This doesn't mean that the area of the circle is 0. It just means that the integral of the given function over the circle's area, using the chosen coordinate system, is 0. This result is correct.

Your setup of the integral in polar coordinates was correct, but there was a mistake in the evaluation of the inner integral.

When evaluating the inner integral, you forgot to include the limits of integration for the variable r. Since r varies from 0 to 2, the correct evaluation of the inner integral should include these limits.

Here's the correct evaluation of the inner integral:

∫ from 0 to 2 (2r^2cos(θ) - rsin(θ)) dr

= [2/3 * r^3cos(θ) - 1/2 * r^2sin(θ)] evaluated from 0 to 2

= [2/3 * 2^3cos(θ) - 1/2 * 2^2sin(θ)] - [0]

= (16/3cos(θ) - 4sin(θ))

Now, plug this result back into the outer integral and continue the evaluation as shown in the previously.